# Read large text file in chunks in a loop

Tags: r, tidyverse, large-data, chunks

I have a large 30GB file that I want to process.

I am trying to read it line-by-line in chunks since it cannot be loaded into memory.

`base::readLines` and `readr::read_lines_chunked` are only able to read in chunks starting from the first line and finishing at the last line.

What I would like to do instead is specify something like this:

```
read lines 1:100
read lines 101:200
read lines 201:300
read lines 301:400
...
until the end of the file
```

I could do this in a loop if I could specify the exact lines to read in, but I think neither of the above mentioned functions allow for this.

is there a way to do this?

the `skip` argument in `readr:read_lines_chunked` allows for skipping the first `n` lines in the datafile, but what I would need is to skip the first `n` and last `m` lines.

For example if the file has `1000` lines:

skip the first `100` and the last `800` would read in `101-200`

Comment: `readr:read_lines_chunked` has a `chunk_size` argument that limits the number of lines to read. So you can combine `skip` with `chunk_size`

Comment: but chunk_size will always read from skip to end, right? how can I tell it to read lines 101:200 for example? if I specify skip=100 it will read from 101-10000000 in chunks but won't stop reading until it reaches the end of the file

Comment: I had a similar problem and I used the LaF package.

Comment: thanks @JamesB looks like that will work!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @JamesB the solution is:

```
library("LaF")
get_lines(file, line_numbers=c(100,101))
```